# OROCRM - related entities not available in the "columns" part in reports and segments

Tags: report, segment, orocrm

Working on the 3.1.14 version of OroCRM, I don't have access to the "related entities" on the "Columns" part of the segment or report designer (see image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU4wO.png) on the 3.1.14 version)

It was working on the 3.1.x-dev  as you can see on the picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWLNT.png).
Please note that he related entities are still available on the filter part. (see picture [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwL6f.png) on the 3.1.14 version)

Can you help me to resolve this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality was disabled intentionally as there are some issues related to UI performance and complexity, so it would not be supported officially anymore.

However, you can enable it back, at your own risk, with the simple form type extension for `Oro\Bundle\MarketingListBundle\Form\Type\MarketingListType` to override `column_column_field_choice_options` option. But in this case, you should handle the performance issues on your own.